# mean of double log transformation

Tags: probability, random-variables, transformation

I have a function $Y=e^{-e^{a+bZ}}$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. I need to find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Is there even a closed-form solution to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

I tried log transformation. $-\ln Y=e^{a+bZ}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[-\ln Y]=e^{a+0.5b^2}$. But then there doesn't seem to be any easy way to find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ using $\mathbb{E}[-\ln Y]$.

Any experts out there? Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.

Comment: I am guessing there is none, since $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_{\Omega} e^{-e^{a+bZ}} \, d\mathbb{P}$. There's not much you can do